# Rails 3.1+ Simple Nested Form validation and Twitter Bootstrap control states

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap, nested-attributes, simple-form

I need some help with handling validations with Twitter Bootstrap properly. The validations are working properly, the issue is Twitter Bootstrap Flash screen. This is what I mean:

No fields filled out and submitted returns: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pvUc.png

The 2 of the required 4 fields submitted returns: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6lCi.png
(notice that it doesn't flash the errors)

I have a basketball app where a Player can be on many Rosters(for player roster archiving purposes) and a Roster can have many Players.

**Roster.rb**

```
class Roster < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :rosterizes
  has_many :players, :through => :rosterizes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
  validates_presence_of :jersey_number, :class_year
  attr_accessible :jersey_number, :class_year, :players, :team_id, :players_attributes
end
```

**Rosterizes.rb**(poorly named I know...)

```
class Rosterize < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :roster
  attr_accessible :player_id, :roster_id
end
```

**Player.rb**

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rosterizes
  has_many :rosters, :through => :rosterizes
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :active
end
```

**_add_player_form.html.erb**
(nested form)

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @roster, :url =>player_added_team_path, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>   
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :players, @roster.players.build do |x| %>
        <%= x.input :first_name %>
        <%= x.input :last_name %>
        <%= x.input :active, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => true} %>
    <%end%>
    <%=f.input :class_year %>       
    <%=f.input :jersey_number %>
    <%=f.input :team_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => params[:id]}%>

    <div class="well">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary icon-plus-sign btn-success', :value => "Add To Team" %>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

**SOLUTION**

My problem is that every time the view was loaded, it was building a new form, thus never getting back the errors on the rollback

I made a change to my controller that builds for the nested form

**Controller**

```
def add_player
     ...
     @new_player = @roster.players.build
end
```

And made the change accordingly to the view

**_add_player_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :players, @new_player do |x| %>
     ...

<%end%>
```

This did the trick, thanks Mober!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason why only the first level validation is shown an the associated not is fairly simple... You do a `<%= f.simple_fields_for :players, @roster.players.build do |x| %>` which buildes the association ALWAYS new when the sites's rendered. What you want to is building the association only if it does not exists yet...

```
<% @roster.players.build if !@roster.players %>
<%= f.simple_fields_for :player do |player_form| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Great catch mober! Your code didn't quite work initially, but your explanation of it always building the association when the site is rendered allowed me to fix it. I'll post the fix on the edit above.

Comment: This logic can be moved to controller. You can just add `@roster.players.build` to controllers 'new' action.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap doesn't actually validate anything, it just provides [styling for validation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts) classes (`error`, `success`, etc).

Now, I'm not a Ruby expert by any means but it looks like you are ending your form early:

```
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :players, @roster.players.build do |x| %>
        <%= x.input :first_name %>
        <%= x.input :last_name %>
        <%= x.input :active, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => true} %>
    <%end%>   <---- here
    <%=f.input :class_year %>       
    <%=f.input :jersey_number %>
    <%=f.input :team_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => params[:id]}%>
```

Should be this?

```
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :players, @roster.players.build do |x| %>
        <%= x.input :first_name %>
        <%= x.input :last_name %>
        <%= x.input :active, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => true} %>        
        <%= f.input :class_year %>       
        <%= f.input :jersey_number %>
        <%= f.input :team_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => params[:id]}%>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: I know that it is a styling validation, and that validation is not handled by Twitter Bootstrap. The form is formated properly, its just how [nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) are set up. Thanks for looking into this though!